Why isn't Self._logChanges logging any changes when used in a View?
I'm new to Swift and am trying to learn what's causing my Views to rerenders?  And more specifically, what View are being re-rendered.
I have Self._logChanges() added the following code, but see nothing in the Console logs in Xcode and nothing in Console.app when monitoring com.apple.SwiftUI (or anything related).  Am I looking in the wrong place or am I using Self._logChanges() wrong?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var count = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._logChanges()

        VStack {
            Text("Count: \(count)")
                .font(.title)
                .padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                count += 1
            }) {
                Text("Increment")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
    }
}


https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-find-which-data-change-is-causing-a-swiftui-view-to-update

Thanks for the link.  If I subscribe to two counts from an @Observable class, then both Text backgrounds change when I'm only updating one.

The body is a computed property the entire thing is redrawn

As per the release notes:

The new _logChanges() method is like the existing _printChanges() one, except that the new method uses the system console, which is useful in some debugging workflows.

If you want to see changes in Xcode's console, use Self._printChanges() instead.
To see changes in the Console.app, run your app in the simulator and then select the simulator in the Console app.

This is a MacOS app

Should specify then somewhere in the post title or at least via tags. If a MacOS app, the printChanges should still apply. As to the console, I am not sure, there seems to be very little information on logChanges().
